Do the Masters of Coin and Whisperers get a nice brooch like the Hand of the King does?
In Game of Thrones, the Hand of the King gets a nice fancy brooch to show off their title:

I'm not sure if this is just a show thing, or if it's described in the books too.
Do the Masters of Coin and/or Whisperers get any similar trinket to mark their position in the books — or, if I didn’t spot it, the show?
If not, are there any fan-designed equivalents?

It's mentioned in the book Game of Thrones, at least when Ned lays his badge before King Robert, when he resigned. When Robert appointed him again after his leg was broken, he handed it back, and threatened to pin it on Jaime Lanister if Ned ever resigned again.
No other members of the small council have a badge of office mentioned. It isn't really needed, as everyone knows who has what positions on the council, and it would be fatal to attempt to impersonate one of them and be caught.
